# Calendar language won't change on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: language-support

I'm super new to this forum and just installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. Previously I had Ubuntu 16.10. What I would like to ask is that if there's a way to change time format on the calendar. I did select my region the Netherlands format and went all the way through checking my time locale which is LC_TIME="nl.NL.UTF-8". My main locale for the whole system is in English (us_US.UTF-8). It does show Dutch time format but only on the login screen. Once I enter my desktop the calendar is in English. I'll attach a screen-captured image of the trouble.

[image: screnshot]

Comment: I don't get it. Your language is English, so the app shows English. Do you just want to change the date format at the top-panel? **25 Aug** instead of **Aug 25** ?

Comment: Can you show us what the command `cat /etc/default/locale` outputs?

Comment: If you want to change the format of the date, time ,... you can do that by going to **settings -> region & language -> format**

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it's already LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 and as the matter of fact, I noticed that my whole operating system is not entirely in English. Some actually in Dutch.

Comment: That's actually what I thought too, changing region but to no avail. I had to reconfigure the locale and put the default in English and simply configure the region and format using Dutch system. It worked on my Ubuntu 16.10 previously. @lolo

Answer (score 2):

Just change the language support settings (`gnome-language-selector`)

[image: Language support - screenshot]

I tested it and it works

[image: Calender - screenshot]

Comment: I already did that to no avail. I even re-configured the locale too. Previously on my Ubuntu 16.10, I was able to set the whole system language in English and using Dutch format but now that I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04, I couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Okay guys, I managed to get this through.

- I went to `dconf-editor` and enter system/locale/region and activate "use default value". Previously before I activated it, it showed my time locale (`locale | grep TIME`) as `LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8`.

  Using terminal would be:

  ```
    gsettings reset org.gnome.system.locale region
  ```
- Then I logged off and logged in back

The calendar appeared using Dutch system which corresponded with my regional format setting.

[image: dconf-editor system/locale/region]

Comment: Great! I was about to ask about that as the next step, but then I found your answer.